# Android - Prevent ListView from shrinking child views

Tags: android, listview, scroll

The Android ListView widget (2.2) has a default behavior that shrinks all the child views when the ListView scrolls.

I want to disable this behavior and do no shrinking of the child views so that they always remain the same size -- how can I do this?

Comment: What does your layout look like?

Comment: I'm building the ListView programatically with FILL_PARENT, and these sets:        setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
setCacheColorHint(0);
setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(200, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: "The Android ListView widget (2.2) has a default behavior that shrinks all the child views when the ListView scrolls." -- got any code? I have not seen this behavior.

Comment: my app works perfectly in all OS except froyo, some elements in the listview shrinks when scrolling

Answer (score -1):

I'm programatically populating a ListView using Views inflated from:

```
< RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/actionitem_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/actionitem_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="TITLE" android:textSize="14dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:layout_below="@+id/actionitem_title"
        android:id="@+id/actionitem_subtitle" android:text="Sub Title"
        android:textSize="12dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:layout_below="@+id/actionitem_subtitle"
        android:id="@+id/actionitem_infoa" android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:layout_below="@+id/actionitem_infoa"
        android:id="@+id/actionitem_infob" android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:id="@+id/actionitem_infoc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionitem_infob" android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/actionitem_image" android:id="@+id/actionitem_infod"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionitem_infoc" android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever the list scrolls there is odd behavior with some of the views shrinking.